# Calling the Firefox webdriver in python

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, web-scraping, geckodriver

I'm using **Debian 9 Stretch** and **Pycharm IDE** and trying to learn web-scramping; I installed the *Selenium* package simply by running:

```
pip install selenium
```

and the Firefox webdriver by running:

```
wget https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.19.1/geckodriver-v0.19.1-linux64.tar.gz
tar -xvzf geckodriver-v0.19.1-linux64.tar.gz.1

chmod +x geckodriver
```

respectively, to download the last release, extract it and make the driver executable. After that, I added the driver to the following path:

```
usr/local/bin
```

I ran all by using the Pycharm IDE terminal and not the built-in Debian terminal.

In order to open Firefox and web-scrape, I run:

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="/usr/local/bin/geckodriver")
```

The last line gives an error message as output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/Example/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 162, in __init__
    keep_alive=True)
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/Example/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 154, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/Example/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 243, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/Example/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 312, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/Example/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: connection refused
```

I'm a newbie both in Python and in web-scraping; please, could someone explain what does go wrong with installation and coding and why I got this error?

In the hope to be clear asking the question, I thanks all in advance for the help.

Comment: Hi @johnashu! I corrected the formatting just now; it only was a way to highlight the line where I got the error! thanks anyway for the comment!

Comment: 1. chmod a+x geckodriver
2. Are you sure your firefox is 64bit?

Comment: Hi @RamazanPolat and thanks for your help too! Anyway, for the first point, I checked in the about Firefox Tab and I confirmed that the Firefox version is the 52.6.0 (64-bit). Lastly, I tried to install GeckoDriver by making it executable with chmod a+x geckodriver  but the error message remains.

Comment: Strange. I run the exact same code in windows and it worked.

Comment: Maybe it is the website you are trying to connect to that is refusing the connection..

Comment: Can you try upgrading Firefox? The most recent stable version is 58. Given that geckodriver is still very much in active development, there could be a mismatch between your driver version and your browser version.

Comment: Hi @johnashu! I'm trying only to open the broser by running webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="/usr/local/bin/geckodriver"). I think  that in order to open a website one has to run driver.get().. but, as written in the question above, I'm a newbie both in python and in using the selenium package..

Comment: Updated just now @Ian, but nothing! It gives exactly the same error!

Comment: Does it work from the command line, i.e., outside of PyCharm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has been solved by removing Mozilla Firefox, that, in Debian 9 Stretch is installed as ESR (Extended Release Support) by default; at the time the Firefox ESR version was 52.0.

After, I installed the by instaling the unstable Firefox version (not Beta) by running on the the terminal as super-user:

```
su -

gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

and adding `deb http://ftp.it.debian.org/debian/ unstable main` to the sources list file.

After, I ran:

```
apt-get update

apt-get install -t unstable firefox
```

to update the software and install Firefox.

By following the guidelines explained in the question to install and run the selenium Python package everything should work fine (at least, for me!).

Hope this will help other users too!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the location of the geckodriver is correct, you can check below:

1. properties of the geckodriver should have the correct permission for the user. You would need to **check the box** "Allow this file to run as a program" or
2. if you you have restricted access, save the geckodriver in your home/username/geckodriver then path it to your firefox. Saving it in your home folder will be able to modify the properties of your geckodriver.

[EDIT] Are your running in command line? If so, you need a virtual display, I have used **pyvirtualdisplay**:

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
display = Display(visible=0,size(800, 600))
display.start()
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="/usr/local/bin/geckodriver")
```

Comment: Hi @Patrick! I allow to run GeckoDriver as a program with 'chmod' statement since I make it executable! Could you specify better the point (2) by explicitely typing what I have to code, please?

Comment: I have edited my answer, with the assumption that you are using command line since I have encountered this error running in the command line.

Answer (score 0):

While woking with [*Selenium-Python Client v3.10.0*](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium) along with [*GeckoDriver v0.19.1*](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) and *Firefox v58.0.2* you have to initialize the *WebDriver* instance and assign it to a variable, which will in-turn initialize the *Web Browser* which will in-turn open the desired *URL* as follows :

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/geckodriver')
driver.get('https://www.google.co.in')
print("Page Title is : %s" %driver.title)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Hi @DebanjanB! I got the error by running driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/geckodriver'); once I run that, Python gives error! Thanks anyway for the tip!